# How Do You Use Lists?

Tags: python, list, bbc-microbit

I am making a morse code translator for the micro;bit. I have button A as the dot, button B for the dash and both together for enter.  The problem is I don't know how lists work so I'm not sure what to do.

```
Alist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Blist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Clist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Dlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Elist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Flist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Glist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Hlist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Ilist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Jlist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Klist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Llist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Mlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Nlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Olist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Plist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Qlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Rlist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Slist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonAB"]
Tlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Ulist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Vlist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Wlist = ["ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Xlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Ylist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonA", "ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
Zlist = ["ButtonB", "ButtonB", "ButtonAB"]
ButtonA = input.button_is_pressed[Button.A]
ButtonB = input.is_button_pressed[Button.B]
ButtonAB = input.button_is_pressed[Button.AB]

if Alist:
    basic.show_string("A")
```

I tried an if statement to check if it's requirements were met and if so, to print the letter A. It's probably simple but I'm not at that skillset yet.

Answer (score 1):

You a 'mapping' from one thing to another, so a Dictionary is a natural approach. Along the lines as shown below. A tuple of the button presses is used as the key to the Dictionary.:

```
morse = {('bA', 'bB', 'bAB'): 'a',
         ('bB', 'bA','bA','bA','bAB') : 'b'
         }
#and so on for all the letters
entry = ('bA', 'bB', 'bAB')

print(morse.get(entry, 'unknown'))
```

gives

`a`